# Local DNS stopped working all of a sudden

Tags: linux, windows, networking, dns, ip

On my local network, I have a number of machines that I SSH to and, until today, I've been able to SSH to them using their network names. Now, if I try to connect to one of my Raspberry Pis from my Win10 machine, I get 
`Could not resolve hostname xxxx: No address associated with hostname`. 
I can still connect using IP addresses.

I've tried `ipconfig /flushdns` but that had no effect. To be honest, this was always an 'it just works' feature for me and I'm not sure if my router (running DD-WRT) or my Windows box is handling the task of local DNS. If it is the Windows box, have any recent Windows 10 updates messed with this stuff?

Comment: Using nslookup on the local computer names I get the following pattern:

<local_computer_name>.<WORKGROUP>

And I can ping that and ssh to it fine. nslookup also reports remote servers as having my local workgroup appended to the end.
Is this normal, or something MS have recently fiddled with?

Comment: Also, I can connect from non-windows PCs using the previous naming convention, which suggests this is an MS change.

Comment: Rebooting DD-WRT does what? Check your network adapter settings, are they reflecting the dd-wrt box address for DNS resolution?